# Javascript: finding a value from an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have the following object:

```
var stuff = {}; 
stuff["jar"] = "biscuit"; 
stuff["cupboard"] = "food";
```

Iterating through the list with an For i loop and getting the value is easy, but how would I get the key?

```
for (var i in stuff) {  
    var key = GET KEY SOMEHOW 
    var val = stuff[i];   
}
```

Comment: Um, the key is `i`. Is this a trick question?

Comment: he's confusing named indexes with position indexes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key is `i`. However, make sure that the key is in your object, not part of the prototype chain.

```
for (var i in stuff) {
  var key = i;
  if (stuff.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
    var val = stuff[i];   
  }
}
```

See also:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty

Answer (score 0):

`var key = i;`

In Javascript's `for (foo in bar)` if `foo` is the index of an object or array and happens to be a string, it should print or assign the string when called.

Answer (score 0):

You already have it:

```
for (var key in stuff) {
    var val = stuff[key];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the value already you may find the key by using this logic :

```
for (var i=0;i<numKeyValuePairs;i++)
{
if(val==key[i])
{
document.write(key[i];
}
}
```